# ajax response I got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

ajax response I got a response and I alert the response it displays [object Object].
then I do this,

```
var Str = JSON.stringify(response);
```

then I alert

```
alert(Str);
```

then I got

```
[{"m_Code":1054,"m_Name":"Vijay"}]
```

now I want to bind the values in html select box

```
<select><option value = "1054">Vijay</option></select>
```

how do I do that? please help me

Comment: Also, somebody's gotta say it - use console.log(Str) in place of alerts, and get used to using a dev console (e.g firebug). Saves a bunch of time; u can easily inspect the objects contents, and they have about 1001 other useful gadgets built in these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX response content is `JSON` Object array probably `OPTIONS` multiple  so you will need to access array using `$.each()` function and manipulate into HTML

```
var response = [{"m_Code":1054,"m_Name":"Vijay"}];
var options = '';
$.each(response, function(i, v){
  //options  += '<option value='+v.m_Code+'>'+v.m_Name+'</option>';
  //OR
  options += $('<option></option>', {value: 1, text: 'abc'})[0].outerHTML
});
$('select').html(options);
```

Comment: It would be better to build a string in your foreach loop and append it once after the concatenating is done. You're accessing the dom too much without any need..

Comment: yes thanks, that will good for performance to reduce to access `DOM` only once

Answer (score 4):

Loop Through Response

```
var str="<select>";
for (i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
    str +="<option value='"+response.d[i].m_Code+"'>"+response.d[i].m_Name+"</option>"
}
str +="</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is an array containing an object. You can get the value and name with:

```
var value = response[0].m_Code;
var name = response[0].m_Name;
```